# What is maximum number of circles that can be rendered in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm attempting to test the performance of rendering circles using webgl. I'm using the newest Bokeh release, v0.10.1. I have two linked scatter plots, with box-select tools. When I put more than 120,000 points on each plot (240,000 total) I this error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Is this a hard limit on the number of points that can be drawn?

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, gridplot, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Circle

N = 120000
max = 100
x1 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
y1 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
x2 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
y2 = np.random.random(size = N) * max

output_file('scatter.html')
source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x1 = x1, y1 = y1, x2 = x2, y2 = y2))

left = figure(tools = 'box_select, tap', width = 400, height = 400,
              x_range = (0,100), y_range = (0,100), webgl = True)
right = figure(tools = 'box_select, tap', width = 400, height = 400,
               x_range = (0,100), y_range = (0,100), webgl = True)

left.circle('x1', 'y1', size=10, fill_color = "black", source = source)
right.circle('x2', 'y2', size=10, fill_color = "black", source = source)

p = gridplot([[left, right]])
show(p)
```

**Edit:** I just updated bokeh to v0.11.0, and now I am able to render many more points on each plot (I've tried 500,000).

Comment: Its a browser/system limit, not Bokeh. See some more info at: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1536